# TikZ - replacing arc with ellipse

Tags: tikz-styles, arc, ellipse

Although I have figured out how to draw arcs, I haven't had the same luck with ellipses. I was wondering if you could help me with this. Please find the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- ++(10:2cm)
      (0,0) -- ++(170:2cm);

\draw (0,0) -- ++(55:2.2cm)
      (0,0) -- ++(125:2.2cm);

\draw (0,0) -- ++(82.5:2.4cm)
      (0,0) -- ++(97.5:2.4cm);

% Draw axes
    \draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=1, right, below=0.5; % x-axis
    
% Draw arcs
\draw[thick,red,<->] ([shift=(10:1.9cm)]0,0) arc (10:170:1.9cm);
\draw[thick,red,<->] ([shift=(55:2.1cm)]0,0) arc (55:125:2.1cm);
\draw[thick,red,<->] ([shift=(82.5:2.3cm)]0,0) arc (82.5:97.5:2.3cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not compilable. Because your `%Draw axes` command was not complete. I finish it by assuming you want a label `x` under the coordinate (2,0). If I understand you correctly, here is solution to your question. Like `circle` path, `ellipse` path always draw the full ellipse. If you want to draw an elliptical arc, you can specify two different radii in the option. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- ++(10:2cm)
      (0,0) -- ++(170:2cm);

\draw (0,0) -- ++(55:2.2cm)
      (0,0) -- ++(125:2.2cm);

\draw (0,0) -- ++(82.5:2.4cm)
      (0,0) -- ++(97.5:2.4cm);

% Draw axes
\draw[<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0) node[pos=1, right, below=0.5]{x}; % x-axis
    
% Draw arcs
\draw[thick,red,<->] ([shift=(10:1.9cm)]0,0) arc [start angle=10,end angle=170,x radius=1.9cm,y radius=1.3cm];
\draw[thick,red,<->] ([shift=(55:2.1cm)]0,0) arc [start angle=55,end angle=125,x radius=2.1cm,y radius=1.3cm];
\draw[thick,red,<->] ([shift=(82.5:2.3cm)]0,0) arc [start angle=82.5,end angle=97.5,x radius=2.3cm,y radius=1.3cm];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A big thank you!